# Loop Invariant for Cut Rod Implementation CLRS

Tags: python, loop-invariant

I was wondering what the loop invariant would be for the loop present in lines 4 - 6 of this code and how to prove it during intialization, mantience, and termination.

```
def cut_rod(p, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    q = -inf
    for i = 1 to n:
        q = max(q, p[i] + cut_rod(p, n-i))
    return q
```

I wasn't really sure where to start here so some insight would be great :)

Comment: A loop invariant is some predicate (condition) that holds for every iteration of the loop., thus the loop invariant would be ```1 >= i < n```

Comment: did you mean 1<= i < n

Comment: No I mean't 1 >= 1, since the loop begins with 1 and ends with n

Answer (score 0):

I would say that after each iteration
q = min price of rod with len n cut containing at least 1 piece of len <= i.

This can be proven inductively.

Answer (score 0):

with the q = -inf initialisation you're guaranteed to return the max of q and the recursion of this function